# Python: Troubleshooting ping script

Tags: python

I have hit another "wall"... I have the following script, which appears to work fine on Windows, however when I move it to Linux it seems to lose functionality.

Note: I added the print line(s) statements for troubleshooting.

The following script outputs the contents of the hostsFile when I `print lines`, and then prints each line in turn when I `print line`. But when it reaches the ping execution, it appears to jump straight to the last host in the file. I was wondering if I have missed something clearly obvious (I am still learning python as a newbie).

```
import sys, os, platform, subprocess

plat = platform.system()
scriptDir = sys.path[0]
hosts = os.path.join(scriptDir,'hosts.txt')
hostsFile = open(hosts, "r")
lines = hostsFile.readlines()
print lines
if plat == "Windows":
        for line in lines:
                line = line.strip( )
                ping = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["ping", "-n", "1", "-l", "1", "-w", "100", line],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                )
        out, error = ping.communicate()
        print out
        print error

elif plat == "Linux":
        for line in lines:
                print line
                line = line.strip()
                ping = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["ping", "-c", "1", "-s", "1", "-l", "1",line],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                )
        out, error = ping.communicate()
        print out
        print error

hostsFile.close()
```

Any thoughts/help is appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,

MHibbin

EDIT: Thanks to Wooble for the help... the correct code should be (notice the spacing):

```
import sys, os, platform, subprocess

plat = platform.system()
scriptDir = sys.path[0]
hosts = os.path.join(scriptDir,'hosts.txt')
hostsFile = open(hosts, "r")
lines = hostsFile.readlines()
if plat == "Windows":
        for line in lines:
                line = line.strip( )
                ping = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["ping", "-n", "1", "-l", "1", "-w", "100", line],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                )
                out, error = ping.communicate()
                print out
                print error

if plat == "Linux":
        for line in lines:
                line = line.strip()
                ping = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["ping", "-c", "1", line],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                )
                out, error = ping.communicate()
                print out
                print error

hostsFile.close()
```

Comment: You call `communicate` outside the for loop, so you should expect it to only communicate once. This is not the code you're running on Windows if you're not seeing the same behavior.

Comment: @Wooble, that's the one!.... forgot python is spacing sensitive.

Comment: You should also make sure that `ping` is in the path, or give the full path to it, and that the user executing the script has rights to execute `ping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, as shown, will not work on Windows or Linux. You need to move ping.communicate() inside your loop, otherwise it will execute only once the loop has completed.

Your for loop should read like this:

```
for line in lines:
    print line
    line = line.strip()
    ping = subprocess.Popen(
                ["ping", "-c", "1", "-s", "1", "-l", "1",line],
                stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = subprocess.PIPE
          )
    out, error = ping.communicate()
    print out
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling communicate only once after the `for` loop. At that point in the script, the variable `ping` references the last call to subprocess from the loop.

You can experience that with an empty "hosts.txt" file. You won't get into the loop even once, so you'll get a NameError: `NameError: name 'ping' is not defined`

You should call that inside the loop!

**UPDATE**: Example:

```
for line in lines:
    print line
    line = line.strip()
    ping = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ping", "-c", "1", "-s", "1", "-l", "1",line],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
    out, error = ping.communicate()
    print "out:", out
    print "error:", error
```

Comment: do you mean I should call `hostsFile = open(hosts, "r")` inside the loop?

Comment: no you should call ping.communicate() inside the loop and print the output there too, I'll show you how.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
import sys, os, platform, subprocess

plat = platform.system()
scriptDir = sys.path[0]
hosts = os.path.join(scriptDir,'hosts.txt')
hostsFile = open(hosts, "r")
lines = hostsFile.readlines()
print lines
if plat == "Windows":
        for line in lines:
                line = line.strip( )
                ping = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["ping", "-n", "1", "-l", "1", "-w", "100", line],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                )
                out, error = ping.communicate()
                print out
                print error

elif plat == "Linux":
        for line in lines:
                print line
                line = line.strip()
                ping = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["ping", "-c", "1", "-s", "1", "-l", "1",line],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                )
                out, error = ping.communicate()
                print out
                print error

hostsFile.close()
```

Note the increased indents for the print statements, which should be in the for loops. I have just tried this on my machine and it is printing out a ping for each result in hosts.txt - I assume this is what you wanted?